# Как "правильно" отрисовать текст в pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Для "адаптированной" версии игры "Flappy Bird", необходим показ очков. Но в моём случае, на первом кадре, новое число выглядит примерно вот так(Смотрите скриншот). Подскажите, что написанно неправильно?

```
def score(bird, pipes):
global hiscore
font = pygame.font.Font('Flappy-Bird.ttf', 32)
text = font.render(str(hiscore), True, (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 255))
text_rect = text.get_rect(topleft=(width - 60, 20))
text.set_colorkey((0, 0, 255))

for p in pipes:
    if int(bird.width + bird.bird_rectangle1[2]) > p.pipe_rectangle1[0] and not p.scored:
        hiscore += 1
        p.scored = True
        text = font.render(str(hiscore), True, (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255))
        text_rect = text.get_rect(topleft=(width - 20, 20))
    screen.blit(text, text_rect)
```

[image: Сам скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Перепишите, пожалуйста эту строку:

```
text = font.render(str(hiscore), True, (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 255))
```

на эту:

```
text = font.render(str(hiscore), True, (255, 0, 0))
```

Последний аргумент функции - цвет фона, если его не указывать, он будет прозрачным. Вы его указали, и он нарисовал цифру 1 на ядовитом синем цвете.